# "Customers of product X" or "Product X customers"?

Tags: word-order

Does the word order here change the meaning (even slightly)? Is one version less clear than the other?

- I conducted interviews with customers of product X and product Y.
- I conducted interviews with product X and product Y customers.

I conducted interviews with two sets of customers. Both sentences appear to show that, but does one show that better? Is one ambiguous in some way?

Comment: The question is not about *and:* you have used *and* identically in your two sentences. It's about the word-order of *customers*. The second example is a "garden-path" sentence, because you didn't conduct an interview with product X, but with its customers. So the first is to be preferred. I've edited your question.

Comment: Neither sentence seems idiomatic to me: companies/businesses/shops, etc., have "customers" - products have buyers, purchasers and users..

Comment: Thanks Andrew for editing and answering the question!